# get text from each child of paragraph in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="notes">
<table class="noborder">
   <tr><th class="noborder"><span>notes</span></th></tr>
   <tr><td>
       <p id="notes_p">

       <p>#1: dhhhhhhfdfffg
       </p>

       <p>　qqqqqqqqqqwwwwwwww wweeeeeeeeerr rrrrrrrtt tttttttt　　
       </p>

       <p>#2: asldkflaksdjflks, lasjdlfjsaldfjasldjfoajsdkfjaslkdjlkfasjdfwoidjfalk,zmncv,mznoqeworjoiejflaksdlfjwaf</p>
       </p>
    </td></tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

What I want to do is get the text of each `paragraph` in the `#notes_p`. I have tried using...`$("#notes_p").html()` but I'm only getting a blank. The same with `.text()`. Why is that happening?

How can I get the `innerHtml` properly? because I want to use `.wrap()` in the `paragraph` and then also the text inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paragraphs don't nest so the browser will *fix* your HTML by unwrapping the nesting.

From the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1):

> The `P` element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including `P` itself).

And from [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-content-model):

> **Content model:**
>   Phrasing content.

And [*phrasing content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content) is plain character data and [*phrasing elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing):

> *a* or *em* or *strong* ...

Note that `<p>` is not a phrasing element.

The browser will (probably) end up with this structure in the DOM:

```
<p id="notes_p"></p>
<p>#1: dhhhhhhfdfffg</p>
<p>　qqqqqqqqqqwwwwwwww wweeeeeeeeerr rrrrrrrtt tttttttt</p>
<p>#2: asldkflaksdjflks, lasjdlfjsaldfjasldjfoajsdkfjaslkdjlkfasjdfwoidjfalk,zmncv,mznoqeworjoiejflaksdlfjwaf</p>
```

and the result is that `#notes_p` will be empty and `$('#notes_p').html()` does nothing useful. You can verify this by checking your page's structure with your favorite DOM inspector.

Try replacing `<p id="notes_p">` with a `<div id="notes_p">`, then things will start making sense.

Comment: nice! Thanks for the new info. I didn't know that paragraphs don't nest. Thank you!

Comment: @RC: Careful with a `<span>` though, mixing inline and block elements like that might upset some browsers, probably better to use block duct tape (i.e. `<div>`) instead of inline duct tape (i.e. `<span>`).

Answer (score 1):

you can check from here, http://jsfiddle.net/vbx3x/

```
$('p').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```